# How to check data loading in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I am having a weird issue inside `useEffect()` in my React component. I have to make 2 separate `axios` requests to get data when the page loads. I am trying to use a hook variable to see if the data objects are populated before passing them to the JSX. Here's my current configuration:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/layout/Navbar';
import ContactsCard from '../components/layout/ContactsCard';
import EmailCard from '../components/layout/EmailCard';
import MeetingsCard from '../components/layout/MeetingsCard';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import config from './../config/config';
import axios from "axios";

function SummaryPageNew() {
    let { selectName } = useParams();
    const [contactData, setContactData] = useState();
    const [meetingData, setMeetingData] = useState();
    const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);

    //API calls
    async function getContactData() {
        axios
        .get(config.apiURL + `/affiliations/name/${selectName}`)
        .then((response) => {
            return setContactData(response.data[0]);

        });
    }

    async function getMeetingData() {
        axios
        .get(config.apiURL + `/meetings_attendees/name/${selectName}`)
        .then((response) => {
            return setMeetingData(response.data);
        });
    }

    useEffect((loadingData) => {
        getContactData();
        getMeetingData();
        setLoadingData(false);

        if (loadingData) {
            //if the result is not ready so you make the axios call
            getContactData();
            getMeetingData();
            setLoadingData(false);
        }
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div>
                <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                    <h5>Profile: {selectName}</h5>
                </div>
                {loadingData ? (
                    <p>Loading Please wait...</p>
                ) : (
                    <div className="row">
                        <ContactsCard contactData={contactData} />
                        <EmailCard emailData={meetingData} />
                        <MeetingsCard meetingData={meetingData} />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SummaryPageNew
```

I have tried moving the `setLoadingData(false)` method inside the `axios` calls. If I move it inside the `getMeetingData()` call. This works ... sometimes. Apparently, on some occasions, it loads first and then the `contactData` doesn't get returned. In the current configuration, the DOM renders with "Loading Please wait...". What am I doing wrong here? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't need to specifically pass ````loadingData```` to ````useEffect((loadingData) => {````, it's already available in the top of your component, you can just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues with your code.

1. `useEffect` functions don't take any parameters. Your declaration of `loadingData` as a parameter is covering the actual loadingData variable in your component, and React will not pass a value for this.
2. You're missing a dependency on `loadingData` in your call to useEffect. As is, the function will only execute once and then never again as long as the component stays mounted. So, loadingData never gets set to false. Generally, it is a bad idea to avoid warnings about useEffect dependencies unless you have a very good reason.

My recommended solution would be to avoid storing extra state for the "loading" status. Instead, I would just check whether the two state values have been populated yet, and show the "Loading..." text if either is not.

This leaves you with:

```js
function SummaryPageNew() {
    let { selectName } = useParams();
    const [contactData, setContactData] = useState();
    const [meetingData, setMeetingData] = useState();
    const isReady = contactData !== undefined && meetingData !== undefined;

    //API calls
    async function getContactData() { ... }

    async function getMeetingData() { ... }

    useEffect((loadingData) => {
        getContactData();
        getMeetingData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div>
                <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                    <h5>Profile: {selectName}</h5>
                </div>
                {isReady ? (
                    <div className="row">
                        <ContactsCard contactData={contactData} />
                        <EmailCard emailData={meetingData} />
                        <MeetingsCard meetingData={meetingData} />
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <p>Loading Please wait...</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) is a very powerful library for fetching data asynchronously using hooks. This avoids having to manage complex state which can easily fall out of sync. However, I'd learn the fundamentals of react hooks first!

Comment: These were both great answers but I went with this solution as it was the simplest. Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with async function calls. Javascript doesn't wait for your async functions to complete before it continues with your program. This means your calls are probably still fetching, while you already set loadingData to false. You can fix this by using Promise.all to get a callback when the async functions resolve:

```
//API calls
async function getContactData() {
  return axios
    .get(config.apiURL + `/affiliations/name/${selectName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return setContactData(response.data[0]);
    });
}

async function getMeetingData() {
  return axios
    .get(config.apiURL + `/meetings_attendees/name/${selectName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return setMeetingData(response.data);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  let mounted = true

  return () => { mounted = false }
  
  Promise.all([getContactData(), getMeetingData()]).then(() => { 
    if (mounted) setLoadingData(false) 
  }) 
}, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Also note the `let mounted = true` I've added: you want to make sure this component still exists whenever your async calls complete. If the calls take a while, it's not unthinkable you might have navigated away, for instance.

Finally, it's not a wise idea to disable `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`. With a few changes you can setup your code in such a way that this ignore is no longer needed.

React want you to provide `getContactData`, `getMeetingData` in the dependency array. You can fix that by moving the data fetching function outside of you component. This means they no longer have access to the `selectName` variable, but you can provide that variable as an argument:

```
function SummaryPageNew() {
  let { selectName } = useParams();
  const [contactData, setContactData] = useState();
  const [meetingData, setMeetingData] = useState();
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);

  //API calls

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true

    Promise.all([
      getContactData({ selectName }), 
      getMeetingData({ selectName })
    ]).then(([contactData, meetingData]) => {
      if (!mounted) return
      setContactData(contactData)
      setMeetingData(meetingData)
      setLoadingData(false)
    })

    return () => { mounted = false }
  }, [selectName]);

  return () // Render your component
}

async function getContactData({ selectName }) {
  return axios
    .get(config.apiURL + `/affiliations/name/${selectName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return setContactData(response.data[0]);
    });
}

async function getMeetingData({ selectName }) {
  return axios
    .get(config.apiURL + `/meetings_attendees/name/${selectName}`)
    .then((response) => {
      return setMeetingData(response.data);
    });
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look a react-query, it solves a lot of issues that arise with async functions fetching data.